# IBM MQ - ClassNotFoundException during deserialization of message

Tags: deserialization, ibm-mq, classnotfoundexception, weblogic12c

I'm having trouble deserializing message while consuming from MQ. The app is deployed on weblogic and connects to MQ via weblogic foreign server configuration. the content of the message is a spring integration framework class (ChunkRequest) and i've ensured that all the related libraries are in the weblogic classpath at the receiver side. on the receiver side i get a ClassNotFoundException.

To be doubly sure, i've added the related libraries both to the weblogic libs and also in the application, without much luck. The required classes are also added to `<prefer-application-packages>` in the `weblogic-application.xml`. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

thanks

Stacktrace

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0053: An exception occurred deserializing a message, excepti
on: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null class'.
It was not possible to deserialize the message because of the exception shown.
Examine the linked exception for details of the error.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:126)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsObjectMessageImpl.getObject(JmsObjectMessageImpl.java:363)
        at com.ibm.jms.JMSObjectMessage.getObject(JMSObjectMessage.java:126)
        at org.jba.receiver.JMSReceiver.onMessage(JMSReceiver.java:43)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer$FacadeMessageListener.onMessage(MQMessageConsumer.java:324)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl$JmsProviderMessageListener.onMessage(JmsMessageConsume
rImpl.java:1205)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.honourNoLocal(WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.java:717)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.consumer(WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.java:545)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.driveConsumer(RemoteProxyQueue.java:4350)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.deliverMsgs(RemoteProxyQueue.java:4937)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.deliverMsgsReconnectable(RemoteDispatchThread.java:531)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.deliverMsgs(RemoteDispatchThread.java:504)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.run(RemoteDispatchThread.java:275)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:341)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueu
eManagerImplementation.java:1227)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null class
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1614)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsObjectMessageImpl.getObjectInternal(JmsObjectMessageImpl.java:418)
        at      com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsObjectMessageImpl.getObject(JmsObjectMessageIm     pl.java:351)
```

Comment: What version of IBM MQ jar files are you using?

Comment: I have tried 2 versions of MQ libs 7.5 and 8.

Comment: What specific version ex 7.5.0.7 or 8.0.0.5?

Comment: you are spot on, its 7.5.0.7 and 8.0.0.5.

Comment: hi, did you get any solution ? even i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Well, it sounds like you didn't include all of the required MQ JAR files in your CLASSPATH.

For applications using MQ 7.5.0.*, the list is:

- CL3Export.jar
- CL3Nonexport.jar
- com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
- com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
- com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
- com.ibm.mqjms.jar
- connector.jar
- dhbcore.jar
- fscontext.jar
- jms.jar com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
- jndi.jar
- ldap.jar
- providerutil.jar
- rmm.jar

For applications using MQ 8.0.0.*, the list is (recommended approach):

- com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar

Or for old school MQers, applications using MQ 8.0.0.*, the list is:

- com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
- com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
- com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
- com.ibm.mqjms.jar
- fscontext.jar
- jms.jar
- providerutil.jar

Comment: i have the jar (com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar) packaged in my application and the error prevails.